# Pulling records from Access table based off of date

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I am currently trying to pull specific records based off of the day before. I use SQL mainly when setting up queries. I selected the specific fields I need but set up the where statement at the end as follows:

```sql
WHERE ((([CurrentData].[Closed Date])=Date()-1));
```

I receive a pop up box and get no results for any date I enter in the MM/DD/YYYY format. Any help would be appreciated as I feel like I'm missing only one minor thing somewhere.

---

***EDIT:***

**Sample data:**

```
| ID | Status     | ProductID | Request Date | ReqReviewed | Closed Date | 
|----+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-------------| 
| 1A | Successful | 0001      | 09/10/2000   | Yes         | 09/20/2000  | 
| 2C | Successful | 0001      | 07/20/2001   | Yes         | 07/29/2001  | 
| 5B | Successful | 0005      | 04/08/2001   | Yes         | 05/20/2001  |
```

**Query:**

```sql
INSERT INTO ReconReport ( [ID], [Status], [ProductID], [Closed Date]) 
SELECT 
    CurrentTable.[ID], 
    CurrentTable.[Status], 
    CurrentTable.[ProductID], 
    CurrentTable.[Closed Date] 
FROM 
    CurrentTable 
WHERE
    [CurrentTable].[Closed Date] = Date()-1;
```

Comment: Is your Closed Date only a date?  So that date is same format as Date()?  If not same format (meaning one has time or something) they will not match)

Comment: That Where clause will not cause a pop-up, so `[Closed Date]` is code either misspelled or missing.

Comment: @Brad The close date is only a date, the data type is Date/Time but with no format in the design view. Could this be the problem?

Comment: @Gustav What would cause that pop up then?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post your complete query and some sample data.

Comment: Here's some sample data and the query;

Comment: /------------------------------------------------------------------------\
| ID | Status     | ProductID | Request Date | ReqReviewed | Closed Date |
|----+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-------------|
| 1A | Successful |   0001    | 09/10/2000   |     Yes     | 09/20/2000  |
| 2C | Successful |   0001    | 07/20/2001   |     Yes     | 07/29/2001  |
| 5B | Successful |   0005    | 04/08/2001   |     Yes     | 05/20/2001  |
\------------------------------------------------------------------------/

Comment: The query is as follows;

Comment: INSERT INTO ReconReport ( [ID], [Status], [ProductID], [Closed Date])
SELECT CurrentTable.[ID], CurrentTable.[Status], CurrentTable.[ProductID], CurrentTable.[Closed Date]
FROM CurrentTable
WHERE ((([CurrentTable].[Closed Date])=Date()-1));

Comment: SQL looks good. Build a query object and see if that runs successfully.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the popup that you receive? I'm not seeing anything that should cause a popup.

Answer (score 0):

The first `WHERE` clause in your question references a datasource called `CurrentData`:

```sql
WHERE ((([CurrentData].[Closed Date])=Date()-1));
```

Whereas, when you posted the complete query in the comments, your data source was actually called `CurrentTable`:

```sql
INSERT INTO ReconReport ( [ID], [Status], [ProductID], [Closed Date]) 
SELECT 
    CurrentTable.[ID], 
    CurrentTable.[Status], 
    CurrentTable.[ProductID], 
    CurrentTable.[Closed Date] 
FROM 
    CurrentTable 
WHERE
    [CurrentTable].[Closed Date] = Date()-1;
```

This would indicate the reason for the popup and also why no results would be obtained.

Comment: My apologies, CurrentData should say CurrentTable